# Change textarea text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, textarea

I've searched into this, however nothing is working for me...

I have this **HTML:**

```
<textarea rows="3" name="website" id="website" placeholder=""></textarea>
```

I would like to change this on click with **jquery:** (placed in $(document).ready)

```
$("#website").text(data.website);
```

But it's not working, I have also tried .val() but it's not working either because the `<textarea>` has no value.

*I'm using jQuery 1.9.1*

Comment: what is `data.website` ?

Comment: Are you getting any firebug errors?

Comment: @pXL it's JSON server response. And it's working in other places using `.replaceWith()`

Comment: `.val()` does work. make sure data.website is not undefined. is data actually a json object from jquery, or unparsed, plain text?

Comment: Post a fiddle please?

Comment: `.val()` works: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/MMZ2E/

Comment: their is nothing wrong with `.text()` see it working here `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/sqkMK/ ..  try logging `console.log(data.website);`

Comment: FYI You can easily verify if data.website exists. `if (!data.website) { alert('oops...'); }`

Comment: @MacGyver, there is nothing wrong with your jQuery. It must be `data.website`.

Comment: It looks that your JSON is not as you are expecting, try to do a console.debug(data.website) and inspect it for been sure what are you giving to you textarea

Comment: console log show that the content is "test". Could it be possible that `val()` is not working in jquery 1.9? I might've read this somewhere. `text()` should work tho.

Comment: Paste your code, text wont work with it, the correct method is val, and it works well that that version, check this fidle
http://jsfiddle.net/PPqVe/1/

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies, I did some debugging and the error was from the data.website indeed. val and text are both working.

Comment: @Carlos, `.text()` works just as well as `.val()`.

Comment: @Derek, sure, text also will work, but the correct method is .val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as a solution to prevent confusion for anyone who reads this question. The code above is working however the problem was my "data.website" not jQuery.

Both `.val()` and `.text()` worked.

Comment: and the checked answer is ...?

Comment: The answer that you choice as your answer, I think the first one  :D just for increase ranking :D

Comment: I'm going to choose my answer because all answers are correct and this one describes that the code in question is working, so we can avoid confusing readers. Thanks for your help though :-)

Answer (score 7):

jQuery's `.text(text)` is for replacing the text in an HTML element. `.val(text)` will replace the text in an `<input>` element. Assuming that `data.website` is a valid text string (Which I assume is from jQuery JSON), use this:

```
$("#website").val(data.website);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hSL9h/

If you're still having problems, use `alert(data.website)` or `console.log(data.website)` to check that `data.website` returns a valid text string.

Comment: Ahh, posted before I could, here, have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/BcXGw/

Comment: Their is nothing wrong with `.text()` `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/BcXGw/1/

Comment: @pXL `.text()` works, and so does `.append()`, but `.val()` is generally preferred for form elements.

Comment: @Mooseman  OP's has already tried `.val()`

Comment: @pXL The OP's problem is with `data.website`. He commented that it is now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("textarea#ExampleMessage").val(result.exampleMessage);
```

Comment: Have a fiddle to support your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/BcXGw/ +1

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the OP's code. Using `.text()` works just as well as `.val()`, so it is misleading to suggest otherwise (especially as the OP has stated he has tried both). The problem obviously lies with the data being passed to either `.text()` or `.val()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is not the val, cause if you try

```
$("#website").val("something here");
```

It will run as you want, probably you must check the data.website for been sure what is the value here. Use the inspector with something like

```
console.debug(data.website);
$("#website").val(data.website);
```

then you will be sure what is the value that your are giving to your textarea

http://jsfiddle.net/PPqVe/